# How to make resume script wait for ivtv initialization

Tags: scripts, suspend, power-management, input-devices, ivtv

I have a TV tuner card with an infrared sensor. I have made a script to remove/start ivtv kernel module and shutdown/restart lirc service on suspend/resume.

The problem is that the lirc service start command runs before ivtv has found and initialized the hardware, so it fails.

Is there a way to defer the lirc service start until after the hardware has been initialized?

The script file is:

```
/etc/pm/sleep.d/30_ivtv
```

and its contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Hauppauge PVR250 TV-card and TBS6680 DVB-card are dead after resume, fix it

. /usr/lib/pm-utils/functions

case "$1" in
    hibernate|suspend)
        # VLC prevents sleep
        killall vlc
        # LIRC...
        service lirc stop
        # Disable ivtv to prevent Hauppauge from being dead on resume
        rmmod ivtv
        # Disable TBS6680 dvb card to prevent it from being dead on resume
        rmmod saa716x_tbs_dvb

;;

    thaw|resume)
        modprobe saa716x_tbs_dvb
        modprobe ivtv

        # Here we need to wait until IR sensor device initialization is done!

        service lirc start
;;

    *)
;;
esac

exit
```

Snippet from syslog after resume:

```
lircd-0.9.0[13717]: lircd(devinput) ready, using /var/run/lirc/lircd
lircd-0.9.0[13717]: accepted new client on /var/run/lirc/lircd
lircd-0.9.0[13717]: initializing '/dev/input/event'
lircd-0.9.0[13717]: unable to open '/dev/input/event'
lircd-0.9.0[13717]: Failed to initialize hardware
kernel: [34425.580877] init: Handling lirc-device-added event
...
kernel: [34426.032906] ivtv: Start initialization, version 1.4.3
...
kernel: [34426.093966] ivtv0: Autodetected Hauppauge WinTV PVR-250
...
kernel: [34426.273807] init: Handling i2c-device-added event
kernel: [34426.274758] Registered IR keymap rc-hauppauge
kernel: [34426.274801] input: i2c IR (Hauppauge) as /devices/virtual/rc/rc13/input71
kernel: [34426.274854] rc13: i2c IR (Hauppauge) as /devices/virtual/rc/rc13
kernel: [34426.274856] ir-kbd-i2c: i2c IR (Hauppauge) detected at i2c-2/2-0018/ir0 [ivtv i2c driver #0]
kernel: [34426.275080] init: Handling i2c-device-added event
kernel: [34426.275135] init: Handling rc-device-added event
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `sleep` here:

```
thaw|resume)
    modprobe saa716x_tbs_dvb
    modprobe ivtv

    # Here we need to wait until IR sensor device initialization is done!
    sleep 20
    service lirc start
```

Now, you want to do something really smart, you may want to use upstart.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into upstart, sounds like what I need! I wanted to avoid putting a sleep there, since it's ugly and not solid-state.